# Applied Isotope to replaced elements by replaceWith()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, replacewith

**Update:**
Sorry guys, my bad, my guessing was wrong. It's not because the `replaceWith` is not finished. It's actually due to `isotope` is not applied to the replaced elements. I am currently using `.isotope( 'destroy' )` and rebuild the whole page. It not that sexy because users will see all elements on the page moving. Now it's becoming an `isotope` issue. Is there a better way to do this?

I am using `replaceWith` to replace html elements with new elements from a ajax cal. After that I need to `reLayout`(from `isotope` plugin) my page.

part of my code:

```
success: function(result){
    var data = $(result);
    div.replaceWith(data);
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div#columns").isotope('reLayout');
    });
}
```

The problem is the replaced elements and the old elements are overlapping.I guess it's because the page is relayouted before the replaed html elements are fully loaded. Therefore, I added `$(document).ready()`, but it still didn't work. So I am wondering is there any way to run `reLayout` after `replaceWith` is completed? Thanks.

Comment: replacewith is a synchronous operation... so you can just do the relayout after replaceWith

Comment: Try `setTimeout(function() {
        $("div#columns").isotope('reLayout');
    }, 1);`

Answer (score 1):

Have had the same problem, and am using the following solution (paraphrased in the above example):

```
div.replaceWith(data);
$("div#columns").data('isotope').insert(div).layout();
```

This causes the item that's been replaced to be readded to the Isotope listing, and the exisiting layout is then reapplied (so this appears to maintain state on pre-exisiting filters and sorting!).